Is there a tool to not only display, but also edit included file content in markdown, AsciiDoc or similar?
In some markdown flavours/ tools you can use {include someFile.md} to display content, which is not in the displayed file, but in a referenced one.
In AsciiDoc it even is possible by default via include::someDocument.adoc[].
But is there a way to not only display the content of the file, but also edit it?

Most IDEs, like VS Code and IntelliJ, have a "live preview" feature. The document you edit is in one panel, and the preview is in another panel or in a web browser.
More mature live previews coordinate the panels so that, more or less, the scroll is in sync, and clicking on the preview highlights the source line in the editor.
When "includes" are involved, the include directive in the source file gets highlighted even if the included content is shown in the preview. You would have to open another editing pane to edit the included file.
I'm unfamiliar with all the technologies available. I typically use IntelliJ with the excellent AsciiDoc plugin, which provides a live, as-you-type preview for AsciiDoc documents, including those in Antora projects.
I've done similar with NeoVim, and while the results are workable, there is no cursor/scroll synchronization and no Antora awareness.
Similar capabilities are available for Markdown, but Markdown is not a singular technology. Whether an include capability is available depends on the flavor of Markdown you're using. That means your mileage may vary considerably.

That might be a starting point to finding a solution.
In AsciiDoc it is possible to link a file via link:SecondaryFile.adoc[DisplayName]. If you also add this before or after your import you can quickly change the file in the preview.
Unfortunately at least Vs Code does not recognize this and still displays the original file, but if it would it would be a valid solution.

IntelliJ does do this, so this can be a way! :)
